# Azure Function builder.GetContext().EnvironmentName always 'Development'

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

With reference to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azure_functions_environment)

> When this application setting isn't present when running in Azure, the environment is assumed to be Production.

Even after overriding `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` and `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to Production, I am still getting Development in Azure.

My Azure Function is a running on serverless consumption plan, on Windows environment, runtime version ~3.

Answer (score 2):

Open launch settings
Properties/launchSettings.json
The file contains the json similar to bellow :

```
  "profiles": {
    "YourProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

}
YOu can specify Env variables as in the example.